# I got error from importing Express in Vue App

Tags: vue.js, express, ecmascript-6, vite

```
import express from 'express';
```

I'll trying to import express to my Vue + Vite App but i got an error below, can i import express without using require?

[image]

Comment: Did you run `npm i express` or `yarn add express` in your terminal?

Comment: It's unknown what happens on your side, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . It appears that you try to use Node package in a browser, which cannot work. Express is irrelevant to Vue app, they are different apps that run in different environments

Comment: @DreamBold yes i did

Comment: @EstusFlask in Official documentation of Vue SSR they are using express and vue together

Comment: Not sure if you're making a reference to [that one](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/ssr.html#access-to-platform-specific-apis), but the point is clearly explained there.

Comment: @LackFos The question doesn't mention that SSR is used. If this is the case, Express should be used only in parts that are executed on a server, not in those that run in a browser, like the error shows.

Answer (score 0):

First of, `require` is gone in modern days where you can use `import` everywhere.

Then, Express will not help you a lot in a Vue app because both are not meant to work together: SPA app + backend. The can work separately tho, with the Vue app consuming the Express one as an API.

Finally, showing us the result will not help us finding out the issue. Some configuration needs to be shown.

---

PS: what you're trying to achieve could be useful too, so that you don't spend time doing something that may not be the best way.

Comment: Im, trying to achieve SSR with Vue App, and what configuration should i show?

Comment: @LackFos anything relevant that could help us. An error is just the result, the cause may be interesting. If you want SSR/SSG with Vue, you can [use Nuxt3](https://nuxt.com/).

Comment: Im using laravel as a backend, it will not easy to connect laravel and nuxt together

Comment: 2 solutions: decouple your Laravel as an API and your Nuxt app as a consuming SPA or look at how to render your `.vue` files inside of your Laravel project. Mixing both will be harder and you will need to look if it's even feasible with Laravel (I have no experience in that field).